# can't pop named stash in git

Tags: git, bash, git-stash

I am trying to write set of bash commands that will:

1. Stashes the current changes
2. Checkout and pull SOURCE branch
3. Checkout and pull TARGET branch
4. Merge TARGET branch with SOURCE branch
5. Push changes to TARGET branch
6. Checkout the initial branch
7. Pop the changes from stash

First, I don't know if this is the correct approach to merge two branches using bash script.
The thing is that I am having difficulties stashing and un-stashing named stashes. Here is my script:

```
while getopts "s:t:" option; do
    case "${option}" in
        s) SOURCE=${OPTARG};;
        t) TARGET=${OPTARG};;
    esac
done

if [ "${SOURCE}" = "" ]; then
    echo "SOURCE argument is missing"
    exit 1
fi

if [ "${TARGET}" = "" ]; then
    echo "TARGET argument is missing"
    exit 1
fi

CURRENT_BRANCH=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)

echo "Stash changes..."
git stash save GIT_DEPLOY_STASH

echo "Checkout and pull ${SOURCE}..."
git checkout ${SOURCE}
git pull --rebase origin ${SOURCE}

echo "Checkout and pull ${TARGET}..."
git checkout ${TARGET}
git pull --rebase origin ${TARGET}

echo "Merge and push ${SOURCE}..."
git merge ${SOURCE}
git push origin ${TARGET}

echo "Checkout ${CURRENT_BRANCH}..."
git checkout ${CURRENT_BRANCH}

echo "Pop stash..."
git stash pop stash^{/GIT_DEPLOY_STASH} #<--- THIS ISN'T WORK!
```

Usage example:

```
$ sh ./my-script.sh -s develop -t staging
```

Any idea how to overcome the named stash issue?
Any idea how to improve this script?

Comment: Why do you want to name your stash ? You can simply do a git stash save and then a git stash pop, it will be simpler no ?

Comment: The issue is that there might no be changes so there will no stash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git stash pop` does not allow [regexp revision selection](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) like `stash^{/GIT_DEPLOY_STASH}`

From the [`git stash documentation`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash):

> When no <stash> is given, stash@{0} is assumed, otherwise  must be a reference of the form **stash@{<revision>}**.

But you can use [`git stash apply`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)

> Unlike pop, <stash> may be **any commit** that looks like a commit created by stash save or stash create.

But since you are using it in a script you should use [`git stash create`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash), because it only creates the commit.

> Create a stash (which is a regular commit object) and return its object name, without storing it anywhere in the ref namespace. **This is intended to be useful for scripts**. It is probably not the command you want to use; see "save" above.

So change your script in this way

```
echo "Stash changes..."
GIT_DEPLOY_STASH=$(git stash create 2>/dev/null)

if [ -z ${GIT_DEPLOY_STASH}" ] ; then
    echo "Nothing to stash..."
else
    # echo the stash commit. Useful if your script terminates unexpectedly
    echo "GIT_DEPLOY_STASH created ${GIT_DEPLOY_STASH} ..."
fi


# RESET THE WORKING DIR, BECAUSE STASH CREATE ONLY CREATES THE STASH COMMIT
git reset --hard

...

if [ -n "${GIT_DEPLOY_STASH}" ] ; then
   git stash apply ${GIT_DEPLOY_STASH}
fi
```

Comment: Be aware that, like `git stash`, `git stash create` will do nothing at all (and output nothing) if there is nothing to stash.